# ReferenceError does not occurs?

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I have a question about following code blocks

```
var x = "123" + y;
```

in this code block I am getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

but when I try something like this

```
var x = "123" + y;
var y = "456";
```

It works fine, so why? What is the difference?

Comment: Off to find the var hoisting dupetarget...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: But did you expect `y` to be defined in the first expression?

Comment: I ran these codes seperately